# How can I disable "HTML Checking" in NetBeans?

Tags: html, netbeans, syntax-checking

I'm using NetBean's *Compile on Save* setting, and it's really handy when I'm editing a single file.  But when I'm dealing with a pair of (or more) class files and am switching between the files, I have a problem:

The **Task** tab is nearly worthless since it is littered by HTML "error" messages(+) from many dozens of HTML files in the project that are generated by some external tool.  The number of HTML errors swamps out any actual Java errors.

What I want is one of:

1. A way to tell NB to ignore the directory with the HTML files ("help").
2. A way to turn off HTML "errors" or even to specify HTML2.
3. A way to filter "Task" errors by file type, parent folder: all Java is under "com".

I've perused the settings and properties, but found nothing that helps.

<rant> Yet another reason I hate an IDE that use the "Take Everything in the Folder" approach.... </rant>

*+ = The files are valid HTML but probably not XHTML. Plus, half the messages end abruptly, with something like: "`Unexpected tag <TD> found, expecting one of`*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer, or at least one that works for me (NB 6.8, [YMMV](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/your_mileage_may_vary)):

1. In the **Tasks** tab, click the filter button in the left,
2. Choose **Edit...**
3. In the **Task List Filter** dialog:

   - Click **New**
   - Enter a value for **Name** (such as "No Script Messages"),
   - Uncheck the **Scripting Language Tasks** option
   - Click **OK**.
4. If the filter doesn't work immediately, you may wish to close/open the **Task** window or Netbeans.

Hope that helps someone else.

Answer (score 3):

You can go to Tools->options->Editor->Hint .
You can easily select the right options from there .

Answer (score 2):

I want to use task list to only track my To Do list and It can be a real pain when Netbeans starts showing me @todos from included libraries and all sort of compile errors that I am not interested in. If your use case is like me (not interested in compile errors etc. in task window) then you can do following:- (Netbeans 7.1.2)

1) Tasks window | Right click filter | Edit

To edit the default filter.
Click default filter in left hand panel. 
Right hand panel, under Type tab - un-check compile errors and issues

2) You can go to Tools | Options | Miscellaneous

Go to Tasks tab now.

Here you can add/remove the To Do strings that you want.
You can create your own custom todo string or make sure that only one of them is listed (what you use)

Now apply default filter and you will only see your @todo tasks. sane and sweet :D